# how to get session variable from params in rails (undefined method '*' for nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

In the first controller, I set my session variables:

```
def show
 @item = Item.find(params[:id])
 session[:item_id] = @item.id
 session[:amount] = params[:amount]
end
```

My view sets the amount with a `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag checkout_transaction_path, method: :get do %>
 <%= label_tag :amount %>
 <%= text_field :amount, placeholder: "Total bid amount", autofocus: true %>

 <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The parameters that get sent with this form look like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "amount"=>{"{:placeholder=>\"Total bid amount\", :autofocus=>true}"=>"1111"}, "commit"=>"Confirm offer", "id"=>"1"}
```

The second controller tries to assign the session variable to an instance variable.

```
def checkout
 @item = session[:item]
 @amount = session[:amount]
end
```

However, only `@item` is working. I try to multiply `@amount * 0.10` but get this error: `undefined method '*' for nil:NilClass`

What causes that error? The submit params says it's being submitted, but maybe something is up with the way I try to retrieve it? `session[:item_id]` goes through perfectly.

Comment: The amount is a hash {} not a single key-value pair and the key is the ugliest key I've seen.  I'd change your form so your params are simply params[:amount] = '1111' .

Comment: try puts debugging out your params[:amount] in the show method. You have it as a text field which means it will be a string which wouldn't let you do multiplication on it later unless you convert it ( to_i ) to an integer anyway. However It seems like it is giving you this: `{:placeholder=>\"Total bid amount\", :autofocus=>true}"=>"1111"}` for your amount parameter to me.

Comment: What is crazy is that this hash: `{:placeholder=>\"Total bid amount\", :autofocus=>true}` seems to be the key for your value of `"1111"` to me. I agree with bkunzi01 this is super ugly. Plus why have an amount as a text field?

Comment: submitting that whole weird hash as the key for a value is not intended. i don't understand why it's being sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issue here:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "amount"=>{"{:placeholder=>\"Total bid amount\", :autofocus=>true}"=>"1111"}, "commit"=>"Confirm offer", "id"=>"sam-lipp-abandonment"}
```

In your parameters, you send amount parameters but in amount, you send HTML form `"amount"=>{"{:placeholder=>\"Total bid amount\", :autofocus=>true}"=>"1111"}`, but should send only value what you set in the amount form, and your amount parameters should looks like this example! `"amount"=>"1"`

So this means that your form doesn't work correctly!
Try please replace your form on this one, and in a controller, you will get amount!

```
<%= form_for @new_item, url: checkout_transaction_path do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :amount %>
 <%= f.text_field :amount, placeholder: "Total bid amount", autofocus: true %>

 <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

OR the same code for form_tag

```
<%= form_tag checkout_transaction_path do %>
  <%= label_tag :amount %>
  <%= text_field_tag :amount, placeholder: "Total bid amount", autofocus: true %>

  <%= submit_tag "Submit Post" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem in your form can be here:
you wrote `text_field` instead `text_field_tag`

Also for `form_for` form, you need to add in the controller in a method with variable what you will use in your form, for example, I'm using variable `@new_item` where from you call this form, something like this

```
def new
  @new_item = Item.new
end
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! turns out the issue is three-fold, but your suggestion to change `text_field` to `text_field_tag` was one part of it. the other thirds are - since those params get appended to the url, subsequent attempt to save them as an instance variable would look like `@amount = params[:amount]` and *not* what i had, which was `@amount = session[:amount]`. in fact, i don't even need to bother with assigning that instance in the first controller. AND i should be using `number_field_tag` not `text_field_tag`